# What are good tips and tricks to keep in mind when performing a subject access request for a comprehensive record of self-pertinent data from the met?

Tags: united-kingdom, gdpr, england-and-wales, police, subject-access-request

Bob would like to obtain as comprehensive as possible am archive of all data held on him by the metropolitan police, as well as any other police networks that they may be part of and share data with/on, like for example the PNC.

What self-pertinent data is Bob entitled to or not entitled to obtain?

Is he subject to the requirement to access it for a "policing purpose," as he is accessing it purely about himself as a civilian under subject access rights granted by the data protection act, rather than in any type of capacities as a policeman (which he incidentally is not)?

Is he entitled to all video footage in which he might appear? What are the limits of this?

What ought Bob keep in mind as he formulates his subject access request if he would like it to be as comprehensive a record as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Information Commissioner's Office has published a webpage called "[Get access to your personal data held by the criminal justice system](https://ico.org.uk/your-data-matters/crime/)".

This seems to provide comprehensive advice about what to ask for and who to ask. It also states what the "right to access" does not include.